# Communication between 2 Arduino with HC05 and HC06 modules

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I want to perform a bluetooth communication between 2 Arduino with HC05(master) and HC06 (slave). I success with the pairing of the 2 modules, but when i send a byte that i read from a potentiometer, the slave receive another value, that can be 128, -1, 248. Below there are the Arduino's codes

Arduino master HC05

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BTserial(2, 3); // RX | TX
// Connect the HC-05 TX to Arduino pin 2 RX. 
// Connect the HC-05 RX to Arduino pin 3 TX through a voltage divider.
int potpin = 0;  // analog pin used to connect the potentiometer

void setup() 
{
    // start the serial communication with the host computer
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Arduino with HC-05 is ready");

    // start communication with the HC-05 using 9600
    BTserial.begin(9600);  
    Serial.println("BTserial started at 9600");
}

void loop()
{
    BTserial.println(analogRead(potpin)); 
    delay(100); 
    Serial.println(analogRead(potpin));
}
```

Arduino slave HC06

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo; 
SoftwareSerial slave(2, 3); // RX | TX
// Connect the HC-05 TX to Arduino pin 2 RX. 
// Connect the HC-05 RX to Arduino pin 3 TX through a voltage divider.
int c = 0;
int val;
void setup() 
{
    // start the serial communication with the host computer
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Arduino with HC-06 is ready");

    // start communication with the HC-05 using 9600
    slave.begin(9600);  
    Serial.println("BTserial started at 9600");

    myservo.attach(9);
}

void loop()
{

    if (slave.available())
    {  
        val= slave.read();
        Serial.println(val);
        val = map(val, 0, 1023, 0, 180);
        myservo.write(val); 
        delay(15);    
    }
}
```

Thank you for every answer

Answer (score 1):

In slave sketch you should replace `slave.read()` with [parseInt()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ParseInt).

The `read()` function will read a single byte. When master sends the integer value potpin=130, the function `println(potpin)` will convert it to 3 bytes (coded as ascii character), and will send them. On the slave side you have to read all incoming bytes, stored in string, and convert string in integral variable. `parseInt()` will do that in a single row.

Comment: with slave.parseInt function () makes me not see anything on the serial

Comment: You have to store incoming char in a string and print it to debug. The reference example for [StringToInt](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringToIntExample) corresponds to what you want.

Comment: so if I understand it .... I gotta put parseInt () instead of read () to read the information in the slave program and set the variables in the two sketches for example StringtoInt val; in this way we transform the information sent with println from a string to a proper int value

Comment: Your master sketch is OK; it sends data (as ascii string) and we recognize the end because println sends a `\n` (or `\r\n` on windows) at the end. If you put parseInt() instead of read(), it should work. But maybe there are other problems and you need to see what comes in the stream. If you use the example called [String toInt](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringToIntExample), there is tracing that will show you what is the problem. So try and let us know what is in this stream.

Comment: Much thanks for your help .... I had not realized before now I understand what you mean .... I tried now by example, but if I leave the control with serial.available> 0 does not make me see anything on the monitor .... I removed that function and the value that makes me see and 0

Comment: if I would rather connect the two arduino bluetooth but with a simple serial communication still exist the problem of strings sent? if so, should I use the example of an increasingly Arduino Toint?

Comment: If you have a software serial coming from bluetooth, you have the same behavior as serial through USB. You have examples on www.arduino.cc to explore your needs.

Comment: thank you ... I managed to make it work without bluetooth. Now I miss to understand how to divide 5 values ​​sent via serial and taken from 5 different potentiometers

Comment: these five values ​​should be distributed in the slave to 5 different servo motors

Comment: You can send them 5 in a row, separated by a `;` and ended with `\n`. That will be easy to parse the incoming data. On the receiver if you call `parseInt()` 5 times in a row, at the right time, you will get the values back. The reliability depends on the way you will code that and what you want exactly. You will find plenty of examples, take one that corresponds well to what you do. Happy coding !